# Unable to get value from ResultSet

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I am working on a web application using Java and MySQL.

I created a method that is supposed to return an ArrayList of the respective column name based on the various tables in the database.

However, when I debugged the method, I realised the `while(rs.next())` causes an error. I used this [site](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/retrieving.html) for reference, hence I am not sure what went wrong.

This is the code. Thanks.

```
// Returns the the all the columns in the table
public ArrayList getColumnName(String tableName) throws SQLException {
    ResultSet rs = null;
    List<String> columnName = new ArrayList<String>();

    Statement st = null;
    Connection con = null;

    try {
        // Get a connection from the connection factory
        con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/information_schema", "root", "xxxx");

        // Create a Statement object so we can submit SQL statements to the driver
        st = con.createStatement();

        StringBuilder sql = new StringBuilder("SELECT column_name FROM information_schema.columns " +
                "WHERE table_schema = 'testDB' AND table_name = '");

        sql.append(tableName).append("'");

        rs = st.executeQuery(sql.toString());

        while (rs.next()) { // getting error..
            columnName.add(rs.getString("column_name"));
        }

    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(ModificationPage.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } finally {
        if (con != null || st != null) {
            st.close();
            con.close();
        }
    }

    return (ArrayList) columnName;
}
```

Comment: What is the error you are seeing?

Comment: There is no stack trace, what happens is that from the while(rs.next()), it will step to catch(SQLException ex). Meanwhile, on my web application, the page will refresh while the table component that was supposed to be displayed is not there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [Javadoc of 1.6](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html) (not sure which version of Java you're using):

> Throws: 
>   SQLException - if a database access error occurs or this method is called on a closed result set

It's very, very unlikely that if you actually got to the line where rs.next() was called, that a database error occurred *just then*.  So, the *most likely* result is that the result set was closed.

Please alter your code to the following and see if you still get the error on the same line:

```
while (!rs.isClosed() && rs.next()) { // getting error..
        columnName.add(rs.getString("column_name"));
}
```

Also, Holy SQL Injection Attack, Batman!

Taking the raw string as you're doing and enclosing it within single quotes leads this code to have an SQL injection vulnerability.  Basically all a malicious user has to do is end your query with a single quote (') and run a query of their own afterwards.

Comment: thanks a lot! it is working now. I am merely working on a prototype, so a working component will do for now ;)

Answer (score 1):

So, the exception never happens ?

A query error should be thrown at `rs = st.executeQuery(sql.toString())` if that were the case, but if it make it to `while`and didn't iterate, it's because of an empty resultset

Maybe you're passing wrong arguments to the query ?